# Google +1 and privacy

Tags: privacy, google-plus-1

What happens when I press Google +1 button? Who can understand and view that I liked that article, news or whatever? My friends only, all internet users? Are there any settings to fine-tune this privacy issues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google has an official page for the service: [Google +1 Button](http://www.google.com/+1/button/).

This page explains the details about privacy and fine-tuning settings: [Google +1 button privacy policy](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/buttons-policy).